# Nuget packages suddenly disappeared in my .net maui project

Tags: maui, nuget-package, manage-nuget-packages

I am using Visual Studio Community 2022. I have three .net maui projects in this solution, all of which were working as expected with the require nuget packages showing up in "Manage Nuget Packages.."
Suddenly, I started to get errors that assemblies were missing (CommunityToolkit.Maui, CommunityToolit.Mvvm, etc.). Upon checking "Manage Nuget Packages", they were all gone.

- I have verified that in the project.csproj all of the PackageReferences are there.
- I have verified the proper environment variables.
- The other projects still work.
- I have this project on a separate, older computer and it works. I have compared every aspect of the two that I could think of and cannot find a cause for this behaviour.
- I cannot install the needed nuget packages to this project.
- I cannot restore nuget packages in the PM console.

I have restarted the computer.
I have repaired Visual Studio.
I have deleted the obj/bin folders.
I expected to have the nuget packages available to my project and for my project work work as it was previously.

Comment: Are you sure you are at "installed" tab? Also, what do you have under Tool>Options> Nuget Package Manager  > General and Package Sources? Are you missing checks?

Comment: "cannot install" and "cannot restore" - what specifically happens when you try this?  Do you get errors on the nuget console?  Have you tried clearing the nuget cache?

Comment: Yes, I have cleared the nuget cache.
Under the "General and Package Sources" is the same as it is in the other 2 projects, and in my separate notebook, so I presume it must be correct:
General: Allow NuGet to download missing... Automaticall check for... Default: Packages.config
Package Sources: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json & C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\
*these are checked
--------
When I try to install from the manager, it fails immediately the error message is "Invalid restore input. Missing required property 'ProjectName'."

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days and numerous searches online, I found a reference to the TargetFrameworks tag in the csproj file.

Looking more closely I discovered that "net7.0-windows10.0.22621.0" had changed to "net7.0-windows10.0.22000.0" (as compared to my notebooks file).

When I changed it to "net7.0-windows10.0.22621.0", everything re-appeared, and the project worked as expected.